Conceptual question: how can users trust Solana programs?
I have recently begun learning Solana dev after several years as an Ethereum/Solidity dev, and am still getting a grasp of how things work in Solana.
My understanding is that Solana programs can be changed by the account that created them. If this is the case, how can any user trust any funds put into a Solana program? In Ethereum dev, once a contract is deployed, unless it is specifically upgradable, it's set in stone. So if a contract is verified and made correctly, a user can be sure the creator won't just run off with any funds in the contract.
So my question is, what's the mechanism in Solana that prevents any dapp creator from stealing all funds in their deployed programs?

In Solana you are also able to mark a program as immutable. This means that no new instructions can be added and the program redeployed.
Using the CLI you can make your program immutable
solana program set-upgrade-authority <PROGRAM_ADDRESS> --final

Stack Exchange question ->  How do I make a program immutable?
Once you verify your contract code and publish the IDL, your users can trust that the program you deployed is genuine. Most explorers have a verification tab, which is the best bet for being transparent about your program code.
Solana verification docs -> https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/verified-builds

Thank you that answers the question perfectly.
